# Accessing method of generic type

Tags: java

When I try to access a generic method from my `main` class it gives me an error.
When I do the following:
`Integer key = map.remove(15);`
then Eclipse says **"The method `remove(String)` in the type `IMiniMap<String,Integer>` is not applicable for the arguments `(int)`"** What's the way to access a method of generic type?

```
    public class Tester {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
              IMiniMap<String,Integer> map = new SimpleListMM<String,Integer>();
                map.put("B",15);
                map.put("A",5);
                map.put("R",-5);
                map.put("D",55);
                map.put("Poems",128);
                map.put("Plays",256);

               // System.out.println(map.size());
               // map.put("B", 22);
             //   System.out.println(map.keys());
                //System.out.println(map.toString());

                Integer key = map.remove(15);
        }
    }


public abstract class AbstractListMM<K,V> implements IMiniMap<K,V>{

    protected List <K> keys; 
    protected List <V> vals;

// Initialize the lists of keys and values with a concrete instance
public AbstractListMM()
{
    this.keys = new ArrayList<K>();
    this.vals = new ArrayList<V>();
}
public AbstractListMM(List <K> keys, List <V> vals)
{
    this.keys = keys;
    this.vals = vals;
}

// Return the number of bindings based on the size of the key list
public int size()
{
    return keys.size();
}

// Based on the lists size
public boolean isEmpty()
{
     return (keys.isEmpty() && vals.isEmpty());
}

// Make a (shallow) copy of the keys list and return it
public List<K> keys()
{
     List<K> newKeys = this.keys;
     return newKeys;
} 

// Make a (shallow) copy of the vals list and return it
public List<V> values()
{
    List<V> vals = this.vals;
    return vals;
}

// Use this.indexOf() to locate the given key as quickly as possible
public boolean contains(K key)
{
    int pos = this.indexOf(key);
    if(pos < 0)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;

    /*if(this.indexOf(key) < 0)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;*/
}

// Use this.indexOf() to determine if a given key is present and
// return its associated value; return null if the key is not
// present
//
// TARGET COMPLEXITY: Same speed as indexOf()
public V get(K key)
{
    int pos = this.indexOf(key);
    if(pos < 0)
        return null;
    else 
        return vals.get(pos);
}

// Use this.indexOf() to determine the location of the given
// key/value and remove it from the corresponding lists
//
// TARGET COMPLEXITY: O(N) due to list elements shifting
public V remove(K key)
{
    int pos = this.indexOf(key);
    if(pos < 0)
        return null;
    else 
        return vals.remove(pos);
}
// Find the numeric index of the key as quickly as possible based on
// the type of ListMM being implemented. Return a negative number if
// the given key is not present.
public abstract int indexOf(K key);

// Associate the given key with the given value in the
// lists. Creates an ordering of keys that is compatible with how
// indexOf() works to locate keys.
public abstract V put(K key, V value);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already specify that K type

`AbstractListMM<K,V> implements IMiniMap<K,V>`

will be a type String which is from here:

```
IMiniMap<String,Integer> map = new SimpleListMM<String,Integer>();
```

And therefore you need to supply your remove method `remove(K key)` as a String not an Integer

```
map.remove("B");
```

Comment: Do I have to assign to any variable as the `remove` method has a `V` return type ?

Comment: @John if you want to check if it was successfully removed or not then yes you need a boolean type